# Getting number of active connections by JavaScript / jQuery / Selenium WebDriver

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium

Asking for your help because I'm get stuck.

In my autotests based on Selenium WebDriver + Java I using this construction for checking that there is no background AJAX connections:

```
private boolean hasNoActiveConnections() {
    return (Boolean) ((JavascriptExecutor) browser.getDriver()).executeScript("return $.active == 0");
}
```

But at some pages of WebApplication $.active returning 1 or more (2, 3, 4,...) even if there is realy no background connections and all requests are received response (checked it in FireBug). I can't change code of application, I'm only autotests developer.

Is there way to getting number of active AJAX connection except of $.active jQuery global property? Maybe on pure JavaScript or on WebDriver?

Thanks for your help and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the ticket](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11207):

> JQUERY.ACTIVE IS NOT DECREMENTED ON COMPLETION OF AJAX REQUEST IF AN EXCEPTION OCCURS IN ANY DEFERRED.DONE/FAIL CALLBACKS

So $.active is the right way to check the number of active connections. It just highlights that some ajax requests are failed when $.active remains not equal to zero.

Comment: And there is no other way to check if active connections exists now? What to do in case when web app not using any JavaScript framework like jQuery?